# How can i search for a keyword on a page based on the contents of another page on the same website?

Tags: search, search-engine, google-search, bing-search

If i wanted to search for all websites that are located in Boston
I can do inurl:contact intext:Boston

Also if i wanted to search for all websites that have a careers page and have the term developer i can do
inurl:careers intext:Developer

Is there a way to combine both and search for all websites with a location of Boston that has a careers page with text Developer?

Ideally the solution will be search engine based but open to other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`inurl:contact intext:Boston` isn't the way to go in my opinion, because of the lack of accuracy. You would get every page containing the word `boston`, even those where somebody has a name `boston`, or located in `boston street`, or the like.

On your place i would try this `inurl:developer inurl:jobs OR inurl:careers near:boston`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for my purposes because your query pulls up mostly recruitment agency jobs. 
What i want are jobs on the actual hiring company website. So for example the idea is to filter out companies located in Boston - company.com/contact (look for the keyword "Boston" on this page to obtain companies with a Boston address) then compare the page company.com/careers (Look for the keyword "Developer" on this page) to obtain the results. Not sure if this is possible to do

Comment: recruitment agencies and sites are structuring their information very well. On the other side they are using very sophisticated web scrapers to scrape vacancies. What do you want isn't done with one Google query - because single software companies are not good in structuring their content. With your approach you will get too few useful and too much unuseful information